# How to get child max element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML:

```
<funds>
<bags>
    <bag name="BAG_USD_MAIN" value="10.0" type="USD">
        <pockets>
            <pocket name="bank" value="7.5" expireDate="20130331" />
            <pocket name="award" value="2.5" expireDate="20150501" />
        </pockets>
     </bag>
    <bag name="BAG_USD_SAVINGS" value="290.75" type="USD">
        <pockets>
            <pocket name="bank" value="290.75" expireDate="20130331" />
        </pockets>
     </bag>
    <bag name="BAG_EUR_EXTRA" value="890.0" type="EUR">
        <pockets>
            <pocket name="bank" value="753.0" expireDate="20131231" />
            <pocket name="bank_eng" value="137.0" expireDate="20150501" />
        </pockets>
     </bag>
</bags>
</funds>
```

I'd like to get an XML result list this using XSLT:

```
<bags>
    <bag name="BAG_USD_MAIN" maxExpDate="20150501" />
    <bag name="BAG_USD_SAVINGS" maxExpDate="20130331" />
    <bag name="BAG_EUR_EXTRA" maxExpDate="20150501" />
</bags>
```

That is, grouping the "bags" and show the max expireDate of each.

Can that be achieved with XSLT 2.0? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your input XML is invalid (all of the `pocket` elements are unclosed), but assuming that's fixed, you can do this in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="bags">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bag">
    <bag name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="pockets/pocket/@expireDate">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </bag>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@expireDate">
    <xsl:attribute name="maxExpDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your input XML (after making it valid), the result is:

```
<bags>
  <bag name="BAG_USD_MAIN" maxExpDate="20150501" />
  <bag name="BAG_USD_SAVINGS" maxExpDate="20130331" />
  <bag name="BAG_EUR_EXTRA" maxExpDate="20131231" />
</bags>
```